# Clicking on checkbox to add item to separate div only shows one item at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox

I had a bit of code that *was* working. Basically I have a table with a checkbox next to each row and clicking on a checkbox added that particular row item to a separate div (i.e. it added that row item to a "Favorites List")

I implemented a named function surrounding the code in order to get a context menu working (that was to do the same thing as clicking on the checkbox). Not only is the context menu not working at all, but when clicking on a checkbox **the Favorites div only displays one list item at a time.** Also, the **clicking on the same checkbox to remove a list item stopped working.**

I shuffled some lines around but it just prevented the checkboxes from working entirely. I believe that the source of the problem is the named function, but I don't want to get rid of it because I do want to get the context menu working.

#### Checkbox creation:

```
function makeChx(evt) {
  if (evt.target.type !== "checkbox") {
    $(":checkbox", this).trigger("click");
  }
}

$("#km-table-id tbody tr")
  .append($("<input />", {"type": "checkbox"})
  .addClass("checkbox-class"))
  .on("click", makeChx)
```

#### Adding item to My Favorites div:

```
const $table = $("#km-table-id")
let table = $table.DataTable();
const favesArr = [];

function faveFunc(evt) {

    let data = table.row(this.parentNode).data(),
    checked = $(this).is(":checked"),
    dataIndex = favesArr.indexOf(data);
    if (checked) {
        if (dataIndex === -1) {
            favesArr.push(data); // add item
        }
    } else {
        if (dataIndex > -1) {
            favesArr.splice(dataIndex, 1); // remove item
        }
    }  

    for (var i = 0; i < favesArr.length; i++) {
        ($(".populate-faves").empty()); // removes all previous entries
        $(".populate-faves").append(JSON.stringify(favesArr[i].Titles) + '<br/> <br/>').addClass("faved-doc");  
    }
}; // ------------ faveFunc


$(".checkbox-class").on("click", faveFunc)
$("#add-id").on("click", faveFunc)
```

#### Context menu HTML:

```
<ul class="custom-menu">
    <li data-action="open">Open Document</li>
    <li id="add-id">Set As Favorite</li>
    <li data-action="email"><a href="mailto:?subject=subject">Email Document</a></li>
```

#### My Favorites div HTML:

```
<div id="myFave.hs-gc-header" class="faves-div">
    <p style="font-weight:bold">My Favorites:</p>
    <p class="populate-faves"></p>
</div>
```

### ---

Update: I edited the checkbox rendering section to what I had before, but with no luck:

```
($("#km-table-id tbody tr")).on("click", function(evt) {

      if (evt.target.type !== "checkbox") {
        $(":checkbox", this).trigger("click");
      }
      console.log($("#km-table-id").is(":checked")); // shows as false...why?

    });

  $("#km-table-id tbody tr")
    .append($("<input />", {"type": "checkbox"})
    .addClass("checkbox-class"));
```

The problem appears to be with pushing to the array. Instead of adding the selected item to the end it replaces whichever one is there.

Comment: May be the issue with .on(“click”, makeChx) part.. Try to see if function gets called with console.log something.. If not may be use a function inside .addClass(function) as shown here: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: I did `console.log(makeChx)` inside the function and it is being called onClick. I added `makeChx` to model it after `faveFunc`, but yeah maybe the issue is with it. Update: I removed `makeChx` and added what I had earlier (`($("#km-table-id tbody tr")).on("click", function(evt) {`), but no luck.

Comment: You are asking why `$("#km-table-id").is(":checked")` always returns `false` - I would assume that would be because the element that matches `#km-table-id` is not a checkbox, but it's probably a `<table>`

Comment: You are also calling append input element on the tr table row which causes invalid html markup. Should be appending the tr > to instead.